GraphQL Validate Enum with rule in Lighthouse
In Lighthouse I have an Enum like this
<?php

namespace App\Enums;

use GraphQL\Type\Definition\Description;

#[Description(description: 'Size')]

enum Size: string
{
    case S = 's';
    case M = 'm';
    case L = 'l';
    case XL = 'xl';
}

In a service provider I register it like this:
    $typeRegistry->register(new PhpEnumType(Size::class));

This works all fine.
Now, for some input I want to validate it so that only L and XL are valid for mySize
I was thinking something like this
input SomeInput {
    mySize: Size @rules(apply: ["in:L,XL"])
}

But this throws an error
"statusCode": 500,
"debugMessage": "Object of class App\\Enums\\Size could not be converted to string",
"file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Validation\/Concerns\/ValidatesAttributes.php",

Is there a way to accomplish this without creating my own custom rule?

Since there doesn't seem to be any way check using just what Lighthouse provides I eneded up creating my own custom rule:
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Rules;

use BackedEnum;
use Closure;
use Exception;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\ValidationRule;
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Validation\Validator as ValidationValidator;
use ReflectionClass;

class InEnum implements ValidationRule
{

    public static function register(): void
    {
        Validator::extend('in_enum', self::class . '@passes');
        Validator::replacer('in_enum', function ($message, $attribute, $rule, $parameters, $validator) {
            $data = $validator->getData();
            $value = Arr::get($data, $attribute);
            return (new self)->message($value, $parameters);
        });
    }

    /**
     * @var array<int,string> $parameters
     */
    private array $parameters;

    /**
     * @param array<int,string> $parameters
     */
    public function __construct(array $parameters = [])
    {
        $this->parameters = $parameters;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation error message.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function message(BackedEnum $value, array $parameters): string
    {
        return __('general.validation.in_enum', ['enumClass' => (new ReflectionClass($value))->getShortName(), 'enumValue' => strtoupper($value->value), 'validValues' => implode(', ', $parameters)]);
    }

    /**
     * Check if the rule passes based on the given arguments.
     * @param string $attribute
     * @param BackedEnum | null $value If $value is `null` the rule passes. To prevent this add a "required" rule as well.
     * @param array<int,string> $parameters
     * @return bool
     */
    public function passes(string $attribute, BackedEnum|null $value, array $parameters, ValidationValidator|null $validator = null): bool
    {
        return ($value == null) || in_array(strtoupper($value->value), $parameters);
    }

    /**
     * Run the validation rule.
     * @param string $attribute
     * @param mixed $value
     * @param Closure(string): PotentiallyTranslatedString $fail
     * @return void
     */
    public function validate(string $attribute, mixed $value, Closure $fail): void
    {
        throw new Exception('This functionality has not been implemented yet!');
    }
}

It can be registered in the boot of the AppServiceProvider like this:
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     */
    public function boot(): void
    {
        InEnum::register();
    }

..and used like this:
input SomeInput {
    mySize: Size @rules(apply: ["in_enum:L,XL"])
}

